# How to write a variable into my code with Webpack?

Tags: javascript, webpack

I have a set of files that are compiled into a bundle file. The frontend code is in its own repository and I have some information about it when building the bundle.

I want to put that information into my bundle so that it's accessible from the code, like

```
App.Env = 'development'
```

then access it like this:

```
if (App.Env === 'development') {
    Api.Url = 'http://stating.example.com'
}
```

Comment: https://webpack.js.org/guides/production-build/#node-environment-variable

Answer (score 1):

You can use define webpack plugin.
https://github.com/webpack/docs/wiki/list-of-plugins#defineplugin